# Objective C: Detecting a shake

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer, shake

I'm using the shake api like this:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        [img stopAnimating];    
    }
}
```

How do I detect that the shaking has stopped?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are on the right track, however, there are still more things you need to add to detect shaking:

You can test this by adding an `NSLog` to the `motionBegan` or `motionEnded` methods, and in the Simulator, press `CONTROL + COMMAND + Z`

```
#pragma mark - Shake Functions

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidDisappear:NO];
}

-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        // shaking has began.   
    }   
}


-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        // shaking has ended
    }
}
```

Comment: canBecomeFirstResponder makes sense.